# Windows Performance Analyzerの行の表示が透明になってしまう

Tags: windows

Windows7(x64)に[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)をインストールし、
Windows Performance Recorderで情報を収集しました。
そしてWindows Performance Analyzerで収集した情報を確認しようとしたのですが、
行という行のテキスト表示が透明なためろくに確認できませんでした。
マウスオーバーで表示されているであろうテキストのツールチップは表示されるので、
データが取れていないということではないようです。
このような現象や対処方法に心当たりはないでしょうか？

[image: Windows Performance Analyzer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[マイクロソフト コミュニティ](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-performance-toolkit-%E3%81%AEwindows/d7e34ae6-67d7-4ee2-9f04-cfa80823bce2)に回答がありました。
Windows7の場合、以下の手順で解決できるそうです。

1. Windows Performance Analyzerが起動中であれば終了します。
2. [コントロール パネル]を開きます。
3. [デスクトップのカスタマイズ]を選択します。
4. [個人設定]を選択します。
5. [ウィンドウの色とデザイン]を選択します。
6. [デザインの詳細設定...]を選択します。
7. [指定する部分]リストから、"メッセージ ボックス"を選択します。
8. [フォント]リストの"メイリオ"を、"MS Pゴシック"に変更します。
9. [適用]をクリックします。
10. [OK]をクリックします。
11. Windows Performance Analyzerを起動し、テキストが表示されることを確認します。